# With AutoMapper how do I ignore a destination property that does not have an accessible getter

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to ignore a property that is on my destination but it doesn't have an accessible getter...

```
.ForMember(opt=>opt.nameSpecial, src=>src.Ignore())
```

When I do this I get "The property 'X.nameSpecial' cannot be used in this context because the 'get' accessor is inaccessible

Comment: [AutoMapper Ignore Property](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ignore-using-automapper-in-csharp/) that may be useful.

Comment: Do you have access to class (to change it) to add the `[Ignore]` attribute? https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html#ignoring-members

Comment: Do you have a property `nameSpecial` which does not have a getter? Why do you define such a property? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which shows the classes you have and the mapping you want to perform.

Comment: @Leo - I tried that - didn't work. I didn't delve any deeper as I assumed that given I'm registering a mapper for this type the attribute approach won't work. Though that may not be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ForMember` overload that takes name of the property as parameter.

```
.ForMember("nameSpecial", src=>src.Ignore())
```

Comment: Usually used when the name isn't known at compile-time

Comment: thank you - what a clever mechanism is provided by auto mapper